# Is "var" in C# analagous to "size_t" in C?

Tags: c#, c++, c, variables

I have gotten used to using size_t in my C++ code by way of C due to a professor's insistence and I was curious if 'var' in C# is the same sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking whether the use of `var` is like `size_t` in that you don't actually need to use `size_t`, you can get away with an `int`, then yes, they are kind of similar in that respect.

However, they differ in that `size_t` is about making your code more explicit, whilst `var` is about removing some redundant explicitness for the benefit of readability.

So the readability of the following code can be improved with `var`:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, char>> mapping = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, char>>();
```

-- vs --

```
var mapping = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, char>>();
```

However, excess use of `var` can harm readability, like in `var f = Foo();`.

Unlike `size_t`, there is absolutely no difference in the code that gets compiled with `var` as opposed to the explicit type.

With `size_t`, one of the benefits is portability. Object sizes might not be an `int` on all platforms, but `size_t` will always be large enough to hold them. This means not using `size_t` could mean your code doesn't compile correctly on some platform.

However, with `var` the code that gets compiled at the end of it is exactly the same. You can use `var` everywhere you possibly can, or you could never use `var` (with the exception of [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)) and it would make no difference.

So whilst it is recommended you *always* use `size_t` where possible in C, `var` is more of a judgement call. It's what you think makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 15):

They have nothing to do with each other!

`var` is used for automatic type inference (the compiler figures out the type of the variable based on the initializer's return type (like `auto` in C++1x)).

`size_t` is just an unsigned integer type in C.

Answer (score 6):

There is a vast difference between the two.

**size_t** is used to represents the size of an object, return by sizeof. It is not a generic way to declare variables.

**var** is an implicit way to declare variables.

Answer (score 2):

C# `var` keyword is most analogous to C++0x 'auto' keyword which is to do with [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference), where the storage type is inferred from the expression, rather than a platform independant way to specify size of the object.

There is no direct equivalent for this in C.

Answer (score 0):

It's not. I don't know about c++ size_t, but I do know that var in C# is exactly the same as declare the variable explicitly, and there is nothing to do with it a runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No, `var` and `size_t` are not the same.

They serve a similar function: they both declare the type of a local variable as part of a statement. But that's where their similarities end.

The variable that both `var` and `size_t` declare has a specific type: `size_t` has the type `size_t`, which is usually `typedef`ed as an `unsigned int`. `var` declares that the type must be inferred by the compiler from the rest of the statement; it could be an `int`, could be a `string`, could be a `List<MyClass>`... the compiler figures that out by analyzing the rest of the statement.